# New laptop with windows 7 via 8 downgrade, format and install windows 10, not activating

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

Just got a new laptop with Windows 7 (via 8 downgrade rights) installed on it.  I reserved a Windows 10 upgrade then installed Windows 10 via the [media creation tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install).

So I skipped doing an upgrade to Windows 10 from 7.

Now Windows 10 says it cannot be activated.
When I run `slmgr.vbs /ato` I'm told "The activation server determined the specified product key is blocked."

Is my only recourse to install 7/8 and then upgrade from that?  Seems really convoluted.